# array_rand() executes all element sql statements php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the next function to save posts

```
  //save post

    function savePost($id_post,$table,$pdo){

         $sql->execute();
         return "saved post".$id_post;
         }
```

Now I make an array to save random posts

```
 $posts = array();

 $posts[] = savePost("1",$table,$pdo);
 $posts[] = savePost("2",$table,$pdo);
 $posts[] = savePost("3",$table,$pdo);
 $posts[] = savePost("4",$table,$pdo);
 $posts[] = savePost("5",$table,$pdo);
```

I return a random element from `$posts` in order to  `$sql->execute();` only this specific post.

```
 echo $posts[array_rand($posts)];
```

It echoes a unique random element, for example `saved post4`, but in the table ALL the array elements were executed and all elements saved their posts. What am doing wrong?

I want to save only **the random value.**

thank you.

Comment: You **already** saved all posts and then for some reason just echoing one of them

Comment: how do I save it only when echo?

Comment: then find a random number and then save a single post with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $posts[array_rand($posts)];
```

just outputs a random entry from `$posts` on-screen. It has no role in *saving* the data. Based on the code you've shown, the process of saving all the posts has already happened (via the repeated calls to `savePost`) before you even generate the random number.

If you want to save just one random post, then you can make an array of all the potential post IDs, and then pick one to save, and pass the randomly-picked entry to the savePost method.

For example:

```
$postIDs = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
echo savePost($postIDs[array_rand($postIDs)], $table, $pdo);
```

Comment: Ok. I see the point here. thank you. The function is a little more complex. every array element would be an array, starting with the id_post and related other strings attached to it. for example, `$potst[]=array(3,"bar","foo","cat")`, I need to retrieve all those elements together when choosing a random `id_post`...and attavh them to the function `savePost` this way `savePost($id_post,"foo","bar","cat",$table,$pdo)`

Comment: ok but that isn't clear from the question. I've answered the question based on the code and data provided, which only shows passing a single ID. So I'd ask you to mark it accepted as-is please. However, if $posts contained more complex data, this idea would still work - `$posts[array_rand($postIDs)]` will select one entry from $posts at random. What kind of values are inside `$posts` doesn't matter to this part of the code, as long as `$posts` is an array of _something_. There's no real need to extract the values separately into savePost - just pass the whole item from $posts as one variable.